# C: Is it legal to subscript an array of incomplete type?

Tags: c, extern, incomplete-type

I can't find the relevant bits in the standard, but gcc and clang allow it, so I guess I' wondering if it's a compiler extension or part of the language. Provide a link if you can.

This can arise with things such as this:

```
extern char arr[];

func(arr[7]); /*No error.*/
```

LATE EDIT: I figured I'd better get a clear understanding of this, which I never did although I had moved on, so starting a bounty which I will award to the first person to give me a clear, concise reference(es) in the C89 standard as to why this is allowed. C99 is acceptable if nobody can find the answer in C89, but you need to look in the C89 standard first.

Comment: For future reference: [The C standard](http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/)

Comment: I am not sure "incomplete type" is the correct phrase here. IMHO an incomplete type is `struct my_type;` Here, `extern char arr[];` is equivalent to `extern char *arr;` which is a fully declared type.

Comment: @Zan Lynx: Not so. The standard explicitly names an array of unknown element count to be an incomplete type. The conversion you describe is a result of using the lvalue of an array in an expression, or declaring an array as a function parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following statement

```
extern char arr[];
```

is a declaration with external linkage, and says that `arr` has a type of array of `char`, which implies that `arr` can have an incomplete type.

According to "6.7 Declarations" (n1570):

> 7 If an identifier for an object is declared with no linkage, the type for the object shall be
>    complete by the end of its declarator, or by the end of its init-declarator if it has an
>   initializer; in the case of function parameters (including in prototypes), it is the adjusted
>   type (see 6.7.6.3) that is required to be complete.

And `arr[7]` equals `*(arr + 7)`, and `arr` need to have a type of "pointer to complete object type", and the type of `arr` will be converted from "array of `char`" to "pointer to `char`" in this case.

According to "6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators" (n1570):

> 3 Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the`_Alignof` operator, or the
>   unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has
>   type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue.

Comment: I'll give you the bounty anyways, but can you cite the location that states that incomplete types are allowed with the extern keyword in such context?

Comment: Excellent answer. I had come across another part of the standard that implies this, because I finally understood the broad scope that the "incomplete types are only usable when size is not required" as being larger than I had thought. Since storage size is not required for an extern declaration, it's therefore allowed to forward-declare them in such manner. Nonetheless, your answer removes all doubt. It's a beautiful answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

"A postﬁx expression followed by an expression in square brackets [] is a subscripted
designation of an element of an array object. The deﬁnition of the subscript operator []
is that E1[E2] is identical to (*((E1)+(E2)))"

From ISO/IEC 9899:201x Committee Draft — April 12, 2011

So arr[7] is perfectly legal, as is 7[arr]. It being a legal expression does not mean it is referring to memory locations your process has permission to access, or the memory locations you intend.

Comment: Thanks! I'm afraid I've worked with C for over a year, but I keep forgetting the little things I don't use for a long time, and it really pisses me off because I always forget the easy stuff and remember the hard stuff in great detail. Makes me feel like a really huge noob. I'm constantly reviewing my references to confirm a suspicion I forgot something.

Comment: It occurs to me that although I had moved on long ago, I never got a clear answer to this question, and it makes me wonder if it's one of those things that everybody does and nobody knows why it's allowed. Placing a bounty.

Comment: @subsentient, The standards documents are copyrighted and available for a fee; you've got several quotes from online draft standards. If you want chapter and verse, look at "6.5.2.1 Array Subscripting" and find the definition section.

Answer (score 3):

Citing from `WG14/N1124 Committee Draft May 6, 2005 ISO/IEC 9899:TC2`

**6.2.5 Types**

> [22] An array type of unknown size is an incomplete type. It is
>   completed, for an identifier of that type, by specifying the size in a
>   later declaration (with internal or external linkage).

```
extern char arr[];
```

shall be an incomplete type.

**6.5.2.1 Array subscripting**

> [2] A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets
>   [] is a subscripted designation of an element of an array object. The
>   definition of the subscript operator [] is that E1[E2] is identical to
>   (*((E1)+(E2))). Because of the conversion rules that apply to the
>   binary + operator, if E1 is an array object (equivalently, a pointer
>   to the initial element of an array object) and E2 is an integer,
>   E1[E2] designates the E2-th element of E1 (counting from zero).

```
func(arr[7]); /* or func(7[arr]); */
```

is identical to

```
func( *(arr + 7) ); /* Memory for arr allocated in other module; */
```

**6.7.5.2 Array Declarators**

> [4] If the size is not present, the array type is an incomplete type. 
>   [8] EXAMPLE 2 Note the distinction between the declarations
>  *extern int *x;
>
>   extern int y[];*
>  The first declares x to be a pointer to int; the
>   second declares y to be an array of int of unspecified size (an
>   incomplete type), the storage for which is defined elsewhere.

x is complete because sizeof x is known. y is incomplete because size of y is unknown while compiling this unit.

```
extern char arr[];
```

is **not** identical to

```
extern char *arr;
```

**Footnote<sup>[92]</sup>**

> If prior invalid pointer operations (such as accesses outside array
>   bounds) produced undefined behavior, subsequent comparisons also
>   produce undefined behavior.

**Annex J.2 Undefined behavior**

> — An array subscript is out of range, even if an object is apparently
>   accessible with the given subscript (as in the lvalue expression
>   a[1](http://ideone.com/l8tjPh)[7] given the declaration int a[4][5]) (6.5.6).
>  — Addition or
>   subtraction of a pointer into, or just beyond, an array object and an
>   integer type produces a result that points just beyond the array
>   object and is used as the operand of a unary * operator that is
>   evaluated (6.5.6).

Compiler is expected to generate code to access 7<sup>th</sup> element of `arr`(0-based) and if definition of `arr` does not contain `7+1` i.e. 8 elements or more, behavior shall be [undefined](http://ideone.com/l8tjPh). But code would be compilable and would exhibit well defined behavior as long as linked `arr` has sufficient size.

Answer (score 2):

For incomplete types you have to do your own memory management and bounds checking, meaning that you know if `arr[7]` is a valid location or not.

Because of this accessing and indexed location within that array is the only way to use incomplete types.

For example you can't initalise an incomplete type `arr[]` with the value of a complete type such as `arr = arr2[5]` even if you know that you allocated enough memory for `arr2` to fit into `arr` you can only memcpy or iterate through each slot.

Comment: But, where in the standard is it said? What book, standard, vague PDF?