# C: Allowed to assign any array to pointer to array of incomplete type

Tags: arrays, c, language-lawyer, ansi-c, incomplete-type

The following seems of questionable legality in C89. I can't figure out why it's allowed. I'm reading the standard and my copy of K&R2 and I still don't get it.

```
char Arr[16];
char (*Durr)[] = &Arr; /*Why is this allowed?*/
```

That's it really. I need a quote from the C89 standard that tells me why this is permitted. This is not a C++ question, it's definitely illegal there. Thanks!

EDIT: This explains where it comes into question in the standard: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c89/c89-draft.html#3.3.16.1

Comment: Where do you see an incomplete type? Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes. That pointer is a pointer to an array of unknown size, which makes it a pointer to an incomplete type.

Comment: Well first of all, `Arr` does have a known size: `16 * sizeof(char)`. Secondly, as I understand it, taking the address and assigning the pointer isn't a problem. Only dereferencing a pointer to an incomplete type is a problem. I'm interested to here what some of the C spec gurus have to say, though.

Comment: As I see it this is no different than `int a; int *p = &a;`.

Comment: This will explain where the confusion comes: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c89/c89-draft.html#3.3.16.1

Comment: What may really bake your noodle is the expression viability difference between `*Durr` and `Durr[0]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initialization in `char (*Durr)[] = &Arr;` requires `Durr` pointing to an array of type compatible with the type of `Arr`.

According to "6.7.6.2 Array declarators" (n1570)

> 6 For two array types to be compatible, both shall have compatible element types, and if
>   both size specifiers are present, and are integer constant expressions, then both size
>    specifiers shall have the same constant value.

Because the array pointed to by `Durr` has an incompleted type, which implies that those two types should be compatible, then compiler should not give error/warning for this initialization.

Comment: I believe this would be the same text as 3.5.4.2 in C89. I only have some ancient draft of C89 so I'm not sure. C89 is quite obsolete...

Comment: @Lee: Thank you. That is exactly the kind of quote I was hoping for. This was a very competent answer. Perhaps you can get me the standard text for this too? This question has a bounty. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20951091/c-is-it-legal-to-subscript-an-array-of-incomplete-type

Comment: @Subsentient C99 and C11 fixed many big flaws and insanities in the C language. For that reason alone, C89 is obsolete. Whether or not you chose to use the completely new features of C99/C11 is another matter.

Comment: `Because the array pointed to by Durr has an incompleted type`! Isn't the size of `Arr` `16`?

Comment: @ajay You missed "if both size specifiers are present".